# Different behavour in launching .vbs file in windows xp and windows 7

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, internet-explorer, vbscript

I've created an app using .vbs file and this .vbs file will link to a javascript html file. I want to try launching it in different platform. I have try lanching it in windows xp (with IE 6) and windows 7 (with IE 11). Normally we will use 'Microsoft Windows Based Script Hose' to open .vbs files.

When I open it in windows 7, it went smoothly.

But when I open it in windows xp, it will open up my application in IE 6 first, then only open up another window for my app. Why is it like this?

Is .vbs file have anything to do with the version of IE we have on our pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could lie in the javascript. 
Is there a redirect anywhere in the javascript?
Instead of redirecting in the same window, it could be redirecting in a new window? 
This would probably be an IE6 issue as there was no new tab feature back then.

Comment: Is it the line 'bOpenNewWindow = true'? IE11 will treat this as opening new tab?

Comment: Sorry, I cant say I recognise this line, but if IE11 opens new tab, then IE6 would probably open new window.